# Cannot invoke listFiles() on the array type File[] in Android AsyncTask class

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask

I would like to ask for some help about the error in my code.
In my program, there is a progress dialog with using `AsyncTask` and a File class will be passed in to  `doInBackground`

Error found on the line - `File[] csvfile = csvLocation.listFiles();`

> Cannot invoke listFiles() on the array type File[]

My Code:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... csvLocation) {
        int count;
        long debugRV;


        File[] csvfile = csvLocation.listFiles();

        try{
            //Put all name of csv into a string array
            for(int j=0;j<20;j++){

                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvfile[j]),"BIG5");
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(isr);
                ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                String line = buffer.readLine();            //read first line to get the column
                String[] cols = line.split("\t");           

                while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("ice","Read next record");
                    Log.d("ice","Line"+ Integer.toString(j)+": "+ line);
                    String[] str = line.split("\t");            //read every single line of record in csv
                    for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                        str[i] = str[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
                        contentValues.put(cols[i], str[i].trim());
                        Log.d("ice",cols[i] + "= " + str[i]);
                    }
                    debugRV = db.insert(tableName[j], null, contentValues);
                    Log.d("ice","Import result for " + tableName[j] +"= ");
                    Log.d("ice", Long.toString(debugRV));


                }
                buffer.close();

            }


        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Caught IOException when importing files", e);
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: please post code in this function listFiles()

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
 File[] csvfile = csvLocation.listFiles();
```

with

```
File[] csvfile = csvLocation[0].listFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for ur example don't need File[] csvfile = csvLocation.listFiles();  line u can use as below,



        try{
                    //Put all name of csv into a string array
                    for(int j=0;j<csvLocation.length;j++){

                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvLocation[j]),"BIG5");
                        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                        String line = buffer.readLine();            //read first line to get the column
                        String[] cols = line.split("\t");           

                        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ice","Read next record");
                            Log.d("ice","Line"+ Integer.toString(j)+": "+ line);
                            String[] str = line.split("\t");            //read every single line of record in csv
                            for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                                str[i] = str[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
                                contentValues.put(cols[i], str[i].trim());
                                Log.d("ice",cols[i] + "= " + str[i]);
                            }
                            debugRV = db.insert(tableName[j], null, contentValues);
                            Log.d("ice","Import result for " + tableName[j] +"= ");
                            Log.d("ice", Long.toString(debugRV));


                        }
                        buffer.close();

                    }


                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Caught IOException when importing files", e);
                }



    or if u want to use listFiles() . try like this,



     @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int count;
            long debugRV;

    File dir = new File("[ur dir name]");
            File[] csvfile = dir.listFiles();

            try{
                //Put all name of csv into a string array
              for (File fdir : dir.listFiles()) {

                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fdir ,"BIG5");
                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                    String line = buffer.readLine();            //read first line to get the column
                    String[] cols = line.split("\t");           

                    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.d("ice","Read next record");
                        Log.d("ice","Line"+ Integer.toString(j)+": "+ line);
                        String[] str = line.split("\t");            //read every single line of record in csv
                        for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                            str[i] = str[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
                            contentValues.put(cols[i], str[i].trim());
                            Log.d("ice",cols[i] + "= " + str[i]);
                        }
                        debugRV = db.insert(tableName[j], null, contentValues);
                        Log.d("ice","Import result for " + tableName[j] +"= ");
                        Log.d("ice", Long.toString(debugRV));


                    }
                    buffer.close();

                }


            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Caught IOException when importing files", e);
            }

            return null;

        }


Note: if u use  second approach don't pass file[] to asynctask.
```

Comment: Your first example says that `csvfile` isn't necessary, but then still uses it in the code.

Comment: dude i haven't used csvfile at all, can u mention where it is

Comment: Now it's going to throw a `FileNotFoundException`. I was trying to get you to notice that your code doesn't do what the original code is meant to do.

Comment: How do u say ?   can  u explain?

Comment: From `listFiles()`, it's evident that a directory is passed into the AsyncTask. The original code then opens and processes 20 files therein. Your code loops over the arguments passed into the AsyncTask, which is presumably only one directory, then tries to open a `FileInputStream` on it, which will throw the aforementioned Exception.

Comment: Hello, I have just studied some example about asynctask. Is it a must for the input of doInBackground to five the length?? I see other examples do so.